# MySQL 5.5 on CentOS 6 -- mysql user 'root@localhost' cannot grant privs

Tags: centos, mysql5.5

This is a new install and I have only set the root passwords for localhost, 127.0.0.1 and .

I know the password is correct as I can log in with root@localhost to the mysql server and can also create users.  However, when I try to grant privileges to the newly created user I get the dreaded "`Access denied for user root@localhost (using password: YES)`" error message.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myUserName'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH 'myUsersPass' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Returns:  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

There's got to be something small that I've missed in my setup, however I cannot find it.  I've been searching for a while and all I can seem to find that relates is a wrong password for the root account, and I know I've got the right one.

I've looked through numerous threads here and they all seem to relate to a lost or unknown password for the root account, which is not the case here.

Comment: what are the results of running SHOW GRANTS;

Comment: show grants returns the full permission list for root@localhost, including the WITH GRANT option.

Comment: @m4rty I have the exact same issue. Have you solved this and could you post if so?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for this that comes to my mind is missing privileges.
Check if your root@localhost has grant privilege. You can find so by looking at `SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE Host='localhost' and User='root';` and checking the `Grant_priv` column. I think you should be able to fix it by setting the column to `'Y'` and doing `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` or restarting mysql.

Comment: Been there, checked that.  The Grant_Priv = Y for root@localhost.